# How to triggers event when an element gets user input without using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My requirement gets user input without using javascript. similar to ng-model angular js:-

Comment: give more details. and btw you can't trigger events on user input without using javascript !

Comment: I assume you want the `"input"` event. `elem.addEventListener("input", func...)`

Comment: ...that's based on your title. The description doesn't match the title.

Comment: Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible but is use html5 attribute oninput in input tag.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("input-id").value;
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "Get input: " + x;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-id" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="input"></p>
```

Comment: It's not possible, but here's an example that shows that it's possible? Sure looks possible to me.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to use java-script for triggering events(of any sort). Angular.js also uses java-script for event binding, As Angular is an reactive framework it provides you an simple way to bind events but under the hood its java-script that is working.

Comment: Events can be, and usually are, triggered by user interaction, not by JavaScript.

Comment: if not by java-script then how do we manage user interaction?
my answer was pretty general that java-script is used to perform events based on user interaction.

Comment: Events are triggered by user interaction. The event handlers themselves are written in JS, but they just respond to the events that were triggered, usually by the user.